# Trying to make a program in C++ that will take an array of strings and count the number of vowels that occur

Tags: c++

My code doesn't have any redlines under it in the IDE but it won't run. I think I am doing something wrong with the comparisons in the if-else statements; I don't think I completely understand the types that are being compared there.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

// Creating some Global Variables that will keep track of the counts of the vowels.
int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0;

// This function will count the number of vowels.
void get_array_stats(std::string arr[], int arr_length) {

    // The goal setting these values to zero is so each time this function is used, the vowel count are reset to 0.
    // That is my intention.
    a = 0; e = 0; i = 0; o = 0; u = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < arr_length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; arr[c].length(); j++) {
            if (arr[c][j] == 'a') {
                a++;
            }
            else if (arr[c][j] == 'e') {
                e++;
            }
            else if (arr[c][j] == 'i') {
                i++;
            }
            else if (arr[c][j] == 'o') {
                o++;
            }
            else if (arr[c][j] == 'u') {
                u++;
            }
        }
    }

}

// This function will display the number of vowels.
void display_stats() {
    std::cout << "[ Vowel Statistics ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e: " << e << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "o: " << o << std::endl;
    std::cout << "u: " << u << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a function that counts the vowels in *one* string?

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: Unrelated: you can simplify your function with some creative use of [the `strchr` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (int c = 0; c < arr_length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; arr[c].length(); j++) {
```

It should be:

```
for (int c = 0; c < arr_length; c++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[c].length(); j++) {
```

Comment: `i` here is the accumulator for the number of letter i's in the strings. `c` was the correct array index. Appropriately enough, the fix is to add `c++`

Comment: You’re right, corrected the mistake

Comment: First time I've seen a question where the language tag is also the answer!

Comment: This is just a typo, the question should be closed and deleted, not answered.

Comment: There is also a mistake in the second line

Answer (score 1):

You've incremented the wrong variable in the first loop.
`for (int c = 0; c < arr_length; i++) {`
But it should be:
`for (int c = 0; c < arr_length; c++) {`

Comment: Don't bother answering questions when it's just a typo. It's just worth a comment.